# existence of inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $M = I - Q$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $Q$ is a general matrix where all of its row sums are no more than $1$ but not all of its row sums are 1, and all entries of $Q$ are nonnegative, I have no idea about how to prove that $M$ is nonsingular.

Comment: Are you sure that the row sums of $Q$ don’t have to be strictly less than $1$? Because as it stands, $Q$ could be $I$, and then $M$ is singular.

Comment: if Q is irreducible and the inequality is strict in at least one row then the result follows from Perron-Frobenius

Comment: you *still* need $Q$ to be **irreducible** or else your most recent edited claim is remains false.  With irreducible $Q$ you may also interpret this as Tausky's refinement of Gerschgorin discs.  In general, if you are making up a claim to prove -- i.e. it is not from a book-- you should explicitly say so.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a more elementary version of the answer give, which also does not use the positivity of $Q$. Take a vector $x$ such that $(Q-I)x = 0$, that is, $Qx = x$. Consider an index $i$ such that $|x_i| = \max |x_j|$. Then $(Qx)_i = x_i$, so
$$
|x_i| = |(Qx)_i| = \left | \sum_{j=1}^n Q_{i,j} x_j \right | \leq \sum_{j=1}^n |Q_{i,j}| |x_j| \leq |x_i| |\sum_{j=1}^n |Q_{i,j}|. 
$$
As the sum is strictly smaller than 1 by assumption, this implies that $|x_i| = 0$, and thus $x = 0$, which means that $Q-I$ is invertible.

By the way, this is essentially the [Gershgorin circle theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)

Comment: Sorry, I reeditted the condition that not all of $Q$'s row sums are 1 but some row sums can be 1.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you should have the sum of all rows $<1$, else $Q$ could be the identity and then $I-Q=0$.

Let's assume that and denote the space dimension $n$.

Your hypothesis is that for all $i = 1 \ldots n$, you have $\sum_{j=1}^n Q_{ij} < 1$ (and $Q_{ij}$ positive). From that, you can bound the matrix norm induced by the infinite norm:

$$\left\lVert Q\right\rVert = \max_i \sum_{j=1}^n |Q_{ij}| < 1 $$

Note that everything I just wrote is valid whether the underlying field is $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, knowing that $\left\lVert \cdot \right \rVert$ is sub-multiplicative, you can prove that for all (complex) eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $Q$ satisfies: 
$$|\lambda| <\left\lVert Q\right\rVert < 1$$

Now, up to a complex change of coordinate (leaving $I$ unchanged), you can consider $Q$ to be triangular, its diagonal values being its eigenvalues. Then $I-Q$ is triangular with non-zero diagonal, since all eigenvalues of $Q$ are different from $1$.

Hence $M=I-Q$ is non-singular.