# Is the matrix in the post invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

Let me describe the matrix I am intersted in.

The square matrix $P\in R^{n\times n}$ with non-negative entries and satisfying:

$\forall 1\le i\le n, \sum_{j=1}^n P_{ij}<1$

I encounterd this matrix in studying the topic related to markov chains.

Is there any dedicated term for calling such matrix $P$?

The main question is:

"Is $P-I$ invertible?"

I have tried to show $1$ is not an eigen value of $P$ to prove its invertibility but still in trouble.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Such a matrix $P$ is called ‘(strictly) sub-stochastic’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Matrix is invertible. Suppose $Pv=v$. Take the maximum absolute entry of v, $v_k$. Then
$$|v_k|=\left|\sum_{j=1}^{n}P_{kj}v_j\right|\leq |v_k|\sum_{j=1}^n|P_{kj}|<|v_k|$$ which means $v_k=0$, so $v=0$, thus 1 is no Eigenvalue of P.
(The first inequality holds by replacing every $v_j$ by the bigger $v_k$, as $v_k$ is the maximum).

Comment: You must assume $v_k>0$.

Comment: oh yeah of course, although it doesn't change the fact that 1 is no Eigenvalue of P, as if $v_k=0$ $v=0$

Comment: $v_k=0$ implies $v=0$ indeed, now that you have corrected your answer by inserting absolute values everywhere (before, it didn't). Another way to correct it was to replace $v$ by $-v$ in case your former $v_k:=\max_iv_i$ was negative.

Comment: Anyway, this is a duplicate. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3701383